# How to use External Ids in a Before Insert trigger?

Tags: trigger, externalid

Our company deploys surveys from an external system. We receive them in Salesforce, but we don't have any relationships. I thought I could create the relationship with an External Ids in a Before Insert trigger, but it didn't work:

```
trigger SurveryTrigger on Survey__c (before insert) {
    if(Trigger.isBefore){
        if(Trigger.isInsert){
            for(Survey__c survey : Trigger.new){
                Account account = new Account();
                account.Foreign_key__c = survey.Account_key__c;
                survey.Account__r = account;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I decided to refactor this into a class and it worked fine when I executed anonymously:

```
SurveyCreateRelationships createRelationships = new SurveyCreateRelationships();

Survey__c testSurvey = new Survey__c();
testSurvey.Account_key__c = 'xxxxxx';

List<Survey__c> testSurveys = new List<Survey__c>();
testSurveys.add(testSurvey);

createRelationships.CreateAccountRelationship(testSurveys);

insert testSurveys;
```

The only thing I can figure is that the before insert doesn't support creating this type of relationship. Has anyone had any similar trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old code contained a few errors.
Here is the Trigger, and test code. This passed the apex test method in my org.

Apex Trigger
`trigger surveyTrigger on Survey__c (before insert) {
    if(Trigger.isBefore){
        if(Trigger.isInsert){
            Map<String, String> extMap = new Map<String, String>();
            Set<String> extIdSet = new Set<String>();
            for(Survey__c survey : Trigger.new){
                extIdSet.add(survey.Account_Key__c);
            }
            for(Account a : [select Id, Foreign_Key__c from Account where Foreign_Key__c IN :extIdSet]){
                extMap.put(a.Foreign_Key__c, a.Id);
            }
            for(Survey__c survey : Trigger.new){
                survey.Account__c = extMap.get(survey.Account_Key__c);
            }
        }
    }
}`

Test class
`@isTest
private class TestSurveyTrigger {
    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
        Account testAccount = new Account(Name='My test account', Foreign_Key__c='test123');
        insert testAccount; 
        Test.startTest();
        Survey__c testSurvey = new Survey__c(Account_Key__c='test123');
        insert testSurvey;
        Test.stopTest();
        Survey__c result = [select Id, Account__c, Account__r.Name, Account__r.Foreign_Key__c from Survey__c where Account_Key__c = 'test123' limit 1];
        system.assertEquals(testAccount.Id, result.Account__c);
    }
}`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't very clear, but the main issue isn't the implementation (although I will give your first approach a try). It seems that Salesforce's external Id matching field doesn't create the relationship when it's run from the Before Insert trigger, but will work when run manually. I can verify that the foreign key is correctly setup as an external Id, but I'm not very clear on what is happening behind the scenes with triggers. I assumed it would work by simply running my logic and then inserting the records. Maybe this functionality isn't supported?

Comment: Nice, gave this a shot and it worked! Still puzzled why 'survey.Account__r = new Account(Foreign_key__c=survey.Account_Id__c);' wasn't working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is correct, In Before Insert building lookup relationship via External ID does not work and creating map of String and ID with 1 SOQL will do the required job as mentioned by Philipp Rackwitz above.