# Associating new contacts/cases with an account?

Tags: apex, trigger

So I'm trying to associate new contacts and cases with an account automatically. I've been creating contacts and cases without an account using an automated script. I understand that at this point, I have to use an APEX trigger although the use case is very simple.

I'm very new to APEX triggers, so I didn't get any further than the logic.

```
 trigger associateWithAccount on Contact (before insert) {
//get Company__c from Contact
//lookup Accounts by Account Name using Company__c
//get AccountID from the result of that lookup
//insert AccountID from Account into AccountID in Contact
 Map<String, String> extMap = new Map<String, String>();
 Set<String> extIdSet = new Set<String>();
 for(Contact c : Trigger.new){
     extIdSet.add(c.Company__c);
 }
 for(Account a : [select Id, Name from Account where Name IN :extIdSet]){
            extMap.put(a.Id, a.Name);
 }
 for(Contact c : Trigger.new){
     c.Account = extMap.get(c.Id);
 }
}
```

However, I keep getting the error that I am illegally assigning from String to Account. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Let's rewrite this with some better variable names while recognizing that Contacts if created from the UI will most likely have their AccountId already populated

```
trigger associateWithAccount on Contact (before insert) {

 Map<String, Account[]> accountsByCompanyName;  // could be more than one Account w/ same name
 Set<String> searchCompanyNames = new Set<String>();

 // Step 1 - gather search keys
 for(Contact c : Trigger.new){
     if (c.AccountId == null && String.isNotBlank(c.Company__c)) {
        searchCompanyNames.add(c.Company__c);
     }
 }

 // Step 2 - find Accounts by contact.Company__c
 accountsByCompanyName = Util.pivotSObjectsByString(Account.Name,
     [Select Id, Name From Account Where Name IN :searchCompanyNames]);

 // Step 3 - Associate Contact in trigger.new to Account
 for(Contact c : Trigger.new){
    if (c.AccountId != null) {continue;}  // nothing to do 
    Account[] matchingAccounts = accountsByCompanyName.get(c.Company__c);
    if (matchingAccounts.isEmpty()) {continue;} // no match
    if (matchingAccounts.size() > 1) {continue;} // ambiguous - do nothing
    c.AccountId = matchingAccounts[0].Id; // unambiguous match
 }
}
```

And handy Util methods (there are other, better flavors of this like SObjectIndex in GitHub)

```
public static map<String,List<SObject>> pivotSObjectsByString(Schema.SObjectField fldToken, SObject[] sobjList) {
    map<String,List<SObject>>   res = new map<String,List<SObject>> ();
    for (Sobject sobj: sobjList == null ? new list<Sobject>() : sobjlist) {
        String pivotKey = (String) sobj.get(fldToken);
        if (res.containsKey(pivotKey)) {
            res.get(pivotKey).add(sobj);
        }
        else {
            Sobject[] typedSobjs = makeTypedSobjList(sobj); // do this so resulting list.getSobjectType() doesn't return null
            typedSobjs.add(sobj);
            res.put(pivotKey,typedSobjs);
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public static Sobject[] makeTypedSobjList(Sobject sobj) {
    return (Sobject[]) Type.forName('List<'+sobj.getSObjectType()+'>').newInstance();
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to extend this to create accounts in the `if (matchingAccounts.isEmpty()) {continue;}` clause and map it to the newly created contact? Reason I'm asking is for recursion issues, not sure if it would cause the trigger to fail

Comment: @erikvm so, the answer is YES but you would need to break step 3 into two passes, step 3a and step 3b (Step 3B is same as current step 3). Step 3a would create the new accounts and add into a new map `newAccountsByCompanyName` that is used to bulk insert, then  merge in `newAccountsByCompanyName` into `accountsByCompanyName` map so step 3b works

Comment: Hmm, not sure I follow. If I do step 3a before  - I'm potentially inserting accounts that should not necessarily be created?

Comment: Step 3a only creates accounts when needed.  I suggest you post a new question in stackexhange with the code.  Comments aren't a good way to resolve this

Comment: I made a new post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/291729/linking-newly-cases-to-accounts-or-creating-new-accounts

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Apex! A couple of points:

Typically if we want to fill in data on a record when it's being added into the system, we want to do this in the "Before" stage. Otherwise, we're performing essentially 2 operations for every record, which isn't very safe.

Your overall order of operations is right on the money, though!

Here is a trigger example from stack-exchange that is doing essentially the same thing :  [How to use External Ids in a Before Insert trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34465/how-to-use-external-ids-in-a-before-insert-trigger) . Check out the accepted answer there :-)

Comment: The other thing is that this contact and the account I want to tie it to are created at the exact same time, so if I do a before insert I'm not sure if it will have time to show up?

Comment: You definitely want to create the account first.

Comment: That's not a problem, I can set the script to a delay after creating the account and before creating the contact.

Comment: Should do the trick. Or wait til you get a success back before proceeding to the next step.

Comment: Check my new code - not sure why I am getting an error.

Comment: shouldnt be c.Id, should be c.Company__c in the last loop?

Comment: and the field should be c.AccountId