# Linking newly cases to accounts or creating new accounts?

Tags: apex

I'm trying to link incoming cases to existing person accounts based on a first name + last name + email combo. If a unique person account exists (ie only one record with the value of first name, last name and email from the newly inserted case) - link the newly created case to that person account. If no match is found - create a new person account and link it to the newly created case. If more than one match is found (ie two person account records with the same first name + last name + email combo) - don't link the case at all.

I've been playing with the code found in another post (and replaced Contact with Case): [Associating new contacts/cases with an account?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93529/associating-new-contacts-cases-with-an-account/249714?noredirect=1#comment437090_249714)

```java
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before insert) {

 Map<String, Account[]> accountsByPersonEmail;  // could be more than one Account w/ same email
 Set<String> searchEmails = new Set<String>();

 // Step 1 - gather search keys
 for(Case c : Trigger.new){
     if (c.AccountId == null && String.isNotBlank(c.SuppliedEmail)) {
        searchEmails.add(c.SuppliedEmail);
     }
 }

 // Step 2 - find Accounts by Case Supplied Email
 accountsByPersonEmail = Util.pivotSObjectsByString(Account.PersonEmail,
     [Select Id, Name, PersonEmail From Account Where Name IN : searchEmails]);

 // Step 3 - Associate Case in trigger.new to Account
 for(Case c : Trigger.new){
    if (c.AccountId != null) {continue;}  // nothing to do 
    Account[] matchingAccounts = accountsByPersonEmail(c.PersonEmail);
    if (matchingAccounts.isEmpty()) {continue;} // how to create new account here and avoid recursion in the trigger?
    if (matchingAccounts.size() > 1) {continue;} // ambiguous - do nothing
    c.AccountId = matchingAccounts[0].Id; // unambiguous match
 }
}
```

```java
public static map<String,List<SObject>> pivotSObjectsByString(Schema.SObjectField fldToken, SObject[] sobjList) {
        map<String,List<SObject>>   res = new map<String,List<SObject>> ();
        for (Sobject sobj: sobjList == null ? new list<Sobject>() : sobjlist) {
            String pivotKey = (String) sobj.get(fldToken);
            if (res.containsKey(pivotKey)) {
                res.get(pivotKey).add(sobj);
            }
            else {
                Sobject[] typedSobjs = makeTypedSobjList(sobj); // do this so resulting list.getSobjectType() doesn't return null
                typedSobjs.add(sobj);
                res.put(pivotKey,typedSobjs);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static Sobject[] makeTypedSobjList(Sobject sobj) {
        return (Sobject[]) Type.forName('List<'+sobj.getSObjectType()+'>').newInstance();
    }
```

My concern is here:

```
if (matchingAccounts.isEmpty()) {continue;}
```

How can I avoid recursion in the trigger? I wish to create a new account for that case and insert that case (and relate that newly created case to the newly created person account)

Comment: before answering this; you should [edit] the OP and do the replacements of Contact to Case so the code matches your verbiage

Comment: Good point, fixed that!